# Calculate Median after Summarize with detail in Stata

Tags: stata, median, summarize

The `summarize` command creates various scalars in Stata. For instance, one can store the mean or min/max values through `gen mean=r(mean)`afterwards.
It is also possible to get more sophisticated measures via the `summarize varname, detail`option. Through this, one also obtains the **median** in form of the 50% percentile.

My goal is to store the **median**. Is there a corresponding scalar?

Where can I obtain information on stored scalars after standard operations like `summarize`? As far as I can see they are not listed in the Stata manuals.

Comment: `summarize` is a command, not a function. (In Stata, commands and functions are disjoint.) Edited accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After each command, one can find out where the results are saved through `ereturn list` or `return list`.

In the case of `summarize varname, detail` the **median** can be obtained through `r(p50)`.

```
summarize varname, detail
return list
local var_median = r(p50)
```

Answer (score 1):

The scalars stored by the `summarize` command are documented at the end of the output of `help summarize` and in the "Stored results" section of the Stata manual documentation for the `summarize` command found in the *Stata Base Reference Manual* PDF included with your Stata installation. In general, returned results for all commands are found in locations analogous to these.